# Process on GKE finishes and restarts by itself

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine :

```
gcloud container clusters create training-cluster     --num-nodes=1     --zone=us-central1-a      --machine-type="n1-highmem-2"     --scopes="gke-default,storage-rw"
```

I get the credentials:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone us-central1-a training-cluster
```

and apply my yaml file:

```
kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
```

The yaml file looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gke-training-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-custom-container
    image: gcr.io/xyz/object-classification:gpu
    args:
      {I put my container arguments here}
```

I can see in the logs that training starts and eventually reaches the end. Problem is that it restarts each time unless I delete my cluster. Is there an argument that I should add to avoid such a behavior?

Comment: Do you want the pod lifecycle to end once the training/logic within your code has been completed?

Comment: Yes, I thought that it was the default behavior

Comment: No, the default behavior is 'Always' restart regardless of the exit code. I will add a response with some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the pod only once (stop the lifecycle as soon as the code/training is done), then you have to change the restartPolicy to Never or OnFailure in your pod yaml definition file.

```
containers:
  - name: my-custom-container
    image: gcr.io/xyz/object-classification:gpu
    args:
      {I put my container arguments here}
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**Always** means that the container will be restarted even if it exited with a zero exit code (i.e. successfully). This is useful when you don't care why the container exited, you just want to make sure that it is always running (e.g. a web server). This is the default.

**OnFailure** means that the container will only be restarted if it exited with a non-zero exit code (i.e. something went wrong). This is useful when you want accomplish a certain task with the pod, and ensure that it completes successfully - if it doesn't it will be restarted until it does.

**Never** means that the container will not be restarted regardless of why it exited.

Now, if you want to run the pod only once multiple times the best approach to go is with Kubernetes CronJobs/Jobs as mentioned by Harsh. That would be the best approach in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the **POD** you set the `restartPolicy: Never` also

The spec of a Pod has a `restartPolicy` field with possible values **Always**, **OnFailure**, and **Never**. The default value is Always.

> The restartPolicy applies to all containers in the Pod. restartPolicy
> only refers to restarts of the containers by the kubelet on the same
> node. After containers in a Pod exit, the kubelet restarts them with
> an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …), that is capped at
> five minutes. Once a container has executed for 10 minutes without any
> problems, the kubelet resets the restart backoff timer for that
> container.

**OR else**

You can use the **cronjobs** or **jobs** in **Kubernetes** which will come and go once the job or container ends the **process**.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

If you can use the **cronjob** you can add **successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0** so once your job finished it will remove that job and **delete** the pod from **cluster** also automatically :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete also the cluster after job has finished?

Comment: there is no specific configuration that will delete the cluster you might need to write custom script for some however you can scale down your nodes to zero atleast.

Comment: some dirty hacks are always there you can invoke the delete cluster command at the end of your program or using some hook maybe.

Comment: i have used this hook with POD not tested yet with job : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/ if you can run at end of container fire the cluster delete command

Comment: Great. Corollary question: if my cluster remains but my pod is deleted, does Google charge something?

Comment: I ask the question because all I want to do is create a cluster, launch training and close everything when training is finished. Like when I use the AI Platform

Comment: yes, looking started charing the for control plane previously it was not used to charge however if your nodes scaled down to zero you wont be charged much, when your jobs comes your nodes get auto scale up and you will get billed that amount of time only. `Cluster management fee of $0.10 per cluster/hour `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235559/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-patrick).